# How to create a custom field type form with several input?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm using Symfony 2.7 I would like to create a custom field type with several input.

Comment: This isn't a symfony1 question

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another form class (or "Type") and use it in your form like:

```
        $builder->add(
            'field_name',
            new MyCustomFormType()
        );
```

it is well described in the docs

http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Comment: what do you mean? This is how you create a "custom field type" as you asked, read the docs I linked.